# NgRx: Passing store value to store selector

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a league management app - with a season selector component that updates the SeasonState.currentlySelectedSeasonId in the store when changed.

In my fixture component I want to use this seasonId to pass to a selector to get fixtures for that season.

However, I get the following error (I am using NgRx Store Freeze) which appears to suggest I am directly mutating the state.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'active' of object '[object Object]'
```

**fixture.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.seasonId$ = this.store
        .pipe(
            select(selectCurrentlySelectedSeason)
        ).subscribe();

    this.store.dispatch(new AllFixturesBySeasonRequested({seasonId: this.seasonId$}));
    this.fixtures$ = this.store
        .pipe(
            select(selectAllFixturesFromSeason(this.seasonId$))
        );
  }
```

If I replace this.seasonId$ in the dispatch of AllFixturesBySeasonRequested, with a number for example, I don't get the error so I assume the issue is passing a store variable to the store?

**fixture.selectors.ts**

```
export const selectAllFixtures = createSelector(
    selectFixturesState,
    fromFixture.selectAll
);

export const selectAllFixturesFromSeason = (seasonId: number) => createSelector(
    selectAllFixtures,
    fixtures => {
        return fixtures.
            filter(fixture => fixture.seasonId === seasonId);
    }
);
```

Other relevant code:

**fixture.actions.ts**

```
export class AllFixturesBySeasonRequested implements Action {
    readonly type = FixtureActionTypes.AllFixturesBySeasonRequested;
    constructor(public payload: { seasonId: number }) {}
}
```

**fixture.effects.ts**

```
@Effect()
  loadFixturesBySeason$ = this.actions$
      .pipe(
          ofType<AllFixturesBySeasonRequested>(FixtureActionTypes.AllFixturesBySeasonRequested),
          mergeMap(({payload}) => this.fixtureService.getFixturesBySeason(payload.seasonId)),
          map((fixtures) => new AllFixturesBySeasonLoaded({fixtures}))
      );
```

**Further info as to the architecture**
I am trying to implement a store solution whereby fixtures (and same will be for results, teams etc) are only loaded by season, rather than fetching all from all seasons. They should then be kept in the store to avoid further API calls if they are needed again, and therefore I need a selector to filter by season.

Comment: If you already loaded the fixtures corresponding to a season in your state with `this.store.dispatch(new AllFixturesBySeasonRequested({seasonId: this.seasonId$}));`, why would you need to pass again the season in the selector ? `select(selectAllFixturesFromSeason)` should be enough.

Comment: @BernardPagoaga because I want fixtures from different seasons kept in the store, so they don't need to be reloaded again, so need to state which season I am selecting from

Comment: *If I replace this.seasonId$ in the dispatch of AllFixturesBySeasonRequested, with a number for example, I don't get the error so I assume the issue is passing a store variable to the store?* Then what is the value of this.season$ ? By convention it seems to be an observable ?

Comment: @BernardPagoaga hmm yes I had it as type Observable<number> actually, but then I get compile errors, type Observable<number> is not assignable to type number so I haven't indicated the type when defining the property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a number to your action instead of an observable, such as :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.store
    .pipe(
        select(selectCurrentlySelectedSeason)
    ).subscribe(seasonId => {
        this.store.dispatch(new AllFixturesBySeasonRequested({seasonId}));
        this.fixtures$ = this.store
        .pipe(
             select(selectAllFixturesFromSeason(seasonId))
         );
    });

}
```

If needed you might need to use switchMap to avoid nesting subscriptions.

Comment: Great, that's much better since it also updates when the seasonId store value changes. However - what do you mean about nested subscriptions - your code doesn't include any? fixtures$ is using async pipe